# Bivariate fundamental theorem of calculus using double integral

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I need to express the function $f(x,y)$ using its first partial derivatives. Is the following expression correct?

$$
f(x,y)=f(a,b)+\intop_{a}^{x}\intop_{b}^{y}(f_{1}(t,s)+f_{2}(t,s)) \, ds \, dt
$$
where $a,b$ are some constants and $f_{i}(t,s)$ is a partial derivative with respect to $i$-th argument of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

The closer expression that comes to mind is

$$
f(x,y)=f(a,b)+(\gamma)\intop_{(a,b)}^{(x,y)} f_1(t,s)dt+f_2(t,s)ds
$$

over a curve from $(a,b)$ to $(x,y)$, but here you have the integral of a differential form.

Comment: Is there another expression without differential forms but with coordinates?